# Heroku authentification failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have quite a weird issue right now. I've started to create my own RoR applications and I tried to deploy it a few days ago. Everything went fine except a few issues linked to my database handling.

Long story short, I'm working on it, and this morning I had this strange issue. I did my`heroku login` and it worked well, all of my git commands worked, but when I tried to make this command `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I had an error saying:

> Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and try again

But my Internet was working just fine. So I tried `heroku status`, which told me that there were no known issues neither in development nor in production.

So I tried to start the process at the beginning and now I can't even login... I have the `Authentification failed.` error.

EDIT: tried to login on another computer and nothing went wrong.

Comment: Had this issue before - it's generally because Heroku will bring out a new version of their [toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/). I'd highly recommend uninstalling your current version of their Toolbelt & installing the latest

Comment: I tried it and I still got the authentification failed error... Thank you anyways

Comment: I have the same problem. Error: uninitialized constant RestClient::Unauthorized (NameError)

Comment: It might come from Heroku. I tried a heroku status a few minutes ago, and they seem to have some requests. So I guess I'll just wait a bit...

Comment: do you have the full trace log?

Comment: Sadly I don't as I can't run the heroku logs command without being authentificated.

Comment: can you access to git repo on heroku with `git push/pull`?

Comment: I can indeed. I just achieved a successfull push

Comment: but if you push it to heroku, it's means that you have been authentificated so you could to a reroku logs too.

Comment: Well, the git command just ask me for my ssh password, but the heroku authentification recquires my heroku credentials, and is needed to retrieve the logs thanks to the command heroku logs.

Comment: @R0bur you should add the open part of your rsa/dsa key to heroku, and execute `git push/pull` without entering a password

Comment: My open key is already linked to my heroku account. And when I try the command heroku keys:add, authentification is needed.

Comment: @R0bur what do you mean `authentification is needed`

Comment: is seems that your key isn't poken up locally. so make sure that `git  push` require not the password, and make push with key authentication

Comment: When I type the command heroku keys:add, I have a line saying 'Enter your Heroku credentials. Email: '

Comment: Well, Heroku released an update and things seems to be working. Thank you for your interest anyways. https://status.heroku.com/incidents/650

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it occured that it was an error coming from Heroku. They released an update a few minutes ago, and everything seems to be working just fine now.

You might want to check the report: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/650